# Do I finally understand Recursion or am I horribly Wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Firstly I am aware that recursion questions have been asked as I've looked through many of them as well as YouTube and other sources. My main question is have I understood how it works enough or am I horribly wrong?

Below is the code along with how I personally broke it down:

```
def rec(a):  # will end when the condition is no longer greater than 0
    if a > 0:
        r = a + rec(a - 1)  # decrements -1 each time a recurse happens
        print(r)
    else:
        r = 0
    return r


print("\n\nRecursion Results are")
rec(3)
```

break down:

1st call:   # not a recurse, so the -1 doesn't apply
rec(a) = rec(3)
3 > 0, so r = 3 + rec(3 - 1) which equals "6" as the "- 1" is ignored

2nd call:   # 1st recurse so subtract 1
rec(a) = rec(2)
2 > 0, so r = 2 + rec(2 - 1) which equals "3"

3rd call:   # 2nd recurse so subtract 1 again
1 > 0, so r = 1 + rec(1 - 1) which equals "1"

Since the recursion ends if the number is not greater than "0" and "1" is the last number before "0", it means "1" is the final result you'll get as an output.
The reason "1" displays 1st and "6" displays last is due to the fact "1" is
the base or end point while "6" is where the count down starts from, ending at "1"

Comment: You seem to be almost there, but this bit: `"as the "- 1" is ignored"` surely cannot be true!

Comment: @quamrana i had a feeling that was wrong but honestly am lost on how else to explain or break it down, are you saying other than that comment I have it right? if not could you explain what else I got wrong or how I get there? Thank you for the time i appreciate it!

Comment: In your description of the first call at: `r = a + rec(a - 1)`, you start to correctly substitute the values, but a better explanation is: `so r = 3 + rec(2), or 3 plus the return from the next recurse` (which is `3 + 3`, but its `3 + (2+1)`, which is `3 + (2 + (1+0))`

Comment: @quamrana ah I understand what you mean now, otherwise I pretty much understand and explain how it works though? I was trying to explain why the result is:
1
3
6

Comment: May I recommend trying the following tool which is great for stepping through code sections and watching what happens. https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: @user19077881 never heard of that site before but just gave it a run and thank you for sharing! really appreciate it!

Comment: @simmo - you could figure this out easily by running this here - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: @DanielHao yeah the comment above you mentioned it as well, will 100% be using this in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add more print statements for each step and it should be clear.  Your function only knows the answer to rec(0) = 0, so it recurses down until it gets a result, then starts computing the answers to rec(1), etc.:

```py
def rec(a):  # will end when the condition is no longer greater than 0
    print(f'rec({a}) called')
    if a > 0:
        print(f'Compute {a} + rec({a - 1})')
        r = a + rec(a - 1)  # decrements -1 each time a recurse happens
        print(f'{a} + rec({a - 1}) computes to {r}')
    else:
        print(f'termination condition: rec({a}) computes 0')
        r = 0
    print(f'rec({a}) returned {r}')
    return r

print("Recursion results are:")
rec(3)
```

Output:

```
Recursion results are:
rec(3) called
Compute 3 + rec(2)
rec(2) called
Compute 2 + rec(1)
rec(1) called
Compute 1 + rec(0)
rec(0) called
termination condition: rec(0) computes 0
rec(0) returned 0
1 + rec(0) computes to 1
rec(1) returned 1
2 + rec(1) computes to 3
rec(2) returned 3
3 + rec(2) computes to 6
rec(3) returned 6
```